# How to copy files, if the file names start the same, from one folder to multiple folders?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to copy selected files (names mentioned in Excel sheet) from one folder to another/multiple via partial list

The current code copies one file at a time and not all (if the initial file names are same).

How can I copy/move all the files (specified in the sheet) from one folder to another?

```vb
Sub CopyFilesFromListPartial()
    
    Const sPath As String = "E:\Testing\Source"
    Const dpath As String = "E:\Testing\Destination"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    ' Calculate the last row,
    ' i.e. the row containing the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
                 
    ' Early Binding - needs a reference
    ' to 'Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (has intelli-sense)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ' Late Binding - needs no reference (no intelli-sense)
    'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the source folder path.
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = sPath
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder path '" & sFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = dpath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder path '" & dFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long ' current row in worksheet column
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sPartialFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim sYesCount As Long ' source file copied
    Dim sNoCount As Long ' source file not found
    Dim dYesCount As Long ' source file exists in destination folder
    Dim BlanksCount As Long ' blank cell
    
    For r = fRow To lRow
        sPartialFileName = CStr(ws.Cells(r, Col).Value)
        If Len(sPartialFileName) > 3 Then ' the cell is not blank
            ' 'Begins with' sPartialFileName
            sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*")
            ' or instead, 'Contains' sPartialFileName
            'sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*" & sPartialFileName & "*")
            If Len(sFileName) > 3 Then ' source file found
                sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName
                If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...
                    fso.CopyFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...
                    sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination
                Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder
                    dYesCount = dYesCount + 1
                End If
            Else ' the source file doesn't exist
                sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
            End If
        Else ' the cell is blank
            BlanksCount = BlanksCount + 1
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process new files if the initial characters of file names are the same like this:

```vb
' 'Begins with' sPartialFileName
sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*")

Do While sFileName <> ""
        
    If Len(sFileName) > 3 Then ' source file found
        sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName
                
        If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...
            fso.CopyFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...
            sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination
        Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder
            dYesCount = dYesCount + 1
        End If
                
    Else ' the source file doesn't exist
        sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
    End If
            
    sFileName = Dir
        
Loop
```